# self.request.GET[] with href HTML

Tags: python

I need to have self.request.GET[] have the correct code for when the user clicks, based on what they click in the HTML.

Below is Main.py:

```
import webapp2
from data import Fighter
from data import Data
from pages import Page
from pages import ContentPage


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        f = Fighter()
        d = Data()
        p = Page()
        c = ContentPage()

        if self.request.GET[1]:
            self.response.write(c.results(d.fighter_data[0].name, d.fighter_data[0].rank, d.fighter_data[0].age, d.fighter_data[0].hometown, d.fighter_data[0].fights_out_of, d.fighter_data[0].height, d.fighter_data[0].weight, d.fighter_data[0].reach, d.fighter_data[0].wins, d.fighter_data[0].loses, d.fighter_data[0].bio))
        else:
            self.response.write(p.page)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Where if self.request.GET[1]: needs to work if ?fighter=1 is clicked

Pages.py below:

```
class Page(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.page = '''
        <!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        </head>

        <body>

        <a href="?fighter=1">Flweight</a>
        <a href="?fighter=2">Bantamweight</a>
        <a href="?fighter=3">Featherweight</a>
        <a href="?fighter=4">Lightweight</a>
        <a href="?fighter=5">Welterweight</a>

        </body>
        </html>'''

    def content(self):
        content_page = self.page  # set content page equal to page
        content_page = content_page.format(**locals())  # get locals
        return content_page  # return content_page


class ContentPage(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_page = '''
        {name} {age} {rank} {hometown} {fights_out_of} {height} {weight} {reach} {wins} {loses} {bio}'''

    def results(self, name, age, rank, hometown, fights_out_of, height, weight, reach, wins, loses, bio):  # get stuff from page
        results_page = self.data_page  # set results page equal to data page
        results_page = results_page.format(**locals())  # get locals
        return results_page  # returns results_page
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: I think it should be `self.request.GET['fighter']`

Comment: No, that doesn't work.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/request.html#get-data) it looks like it should be right. What does `print(self.request.GET)` show?

Comment: KeyError: 'fighter'

Comment: You shouldn't have `?` in the key.

Comment: Yeah, I just switched it but it gives KeyError: 'fighter' now

Comment: So what does `print(self.request.GET)` show?

Comment: Nothing at all.

Comment: There won't be anything in `self.request.GET` when they first display the page, only when they click on one of the links.

Comment: If I do http://localhost:11080/?fighter=1 it shows the information, but localhost:11080 mainpage shows KeyError

Comment: For whatever reason there is a KeyError

Comment: What else would you expect? `request.GET` only contains keys for URL parameters. If you don't have a `fighter=x` parameter, there won't be a `fighter` key.

Comment: use `if 'fighter' in self.request.GET:` to test if the key exists.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own question. It's:

```
        if self.request.GET:
            if self.request.GET['fighter']:
                self.response.write(c.results(d.fighter_data[0].name, d.fighter_data[0].rank, d.fighter_data[0].age, d.fighter_data[0].hometown, d.fighter_data[0].fights_out_of, d.fighter_data[0].height, d.fighter_data[0].weight, d.fighter_data[0].reach, d.fighter_data[0].wins, d.fighter_data[0].loses, d.fighter_data[0].bio))
            elif self.request.GET['fighter'] == 2:
                self.response.write(c.results(d.fighter_data[1].name, d.fighter_data[1].rank, d.fighter_data[1].age, d.fighter_data[1].hometown, d.fighter_data[1].fights_out_of, d.fighter_data[1].height, d.fighter_data[1].weight, d.fighter_data[1].reach, d.fighter_data[1].wins, d.fighter_data[1].loses, d.fighter_data[1].bio))
            elif self.request.GET['fighter'] == 3:
                self.response.write(c.results(f.name, f.age, f.rank, f.hometown, f.fights_out_of, f.height, f.weight, f.reach, f.wins, f.loses, f.bio))
            elif self.request.GET['fighter'] == 4:
                self.response.write(c.results(f.name, f.age, f.rank, f.hometown, f.fights_out_of, f.height, f.weight, f.reach, f.wins, f.loses, f.bio))
            elif self.request.GET['fighter'] == 5:
                self.response.write(c.results(f.name, f.age, f.rank, f.hometown, f.fights_out_of, f.height, f.weight, f.reach, f.wins, f.loses, f.bio))
        else:
            self.response.write(p.page)
```